# how to increase Drupal site Performance?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

Drupal site is very slow how to recover that,Why performance slow of site,how to speed up of fetch data from mysql db. admin/config/development/performance below Cache pages for anonymous users, Compress cached pages, Aggregate and compress CSS files, Aggregate JavaScript files all are enabled and Uninstalled Unused Module also but still getting performnce is Slow , please help me on this.

Comment: There are way too many possible reasons for your site being slow, and we have no way of telling what it is.

Comment: use devel module to know query log and page load time and also check your server memory and see if you have configured it correctly

Answer (score 0):

you might try some of these resources (for Drupal 7):

1. http://www.drupal4u.org/howtos/drupal-performance-optimization-how-speed-your-drupal-website
2. http://www.slideshare.net/meratneshk/drupal-performance-optimization-best-practices
3. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/118990/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-my-drupal7-site

There are a number of steps that you can take to optimise your Drupal installation.  Some of these will depend on your server management situation.  For example, if you can implement an optimised database environment this can make a difference.

Comment: please don't give just links. provide some clarification also.thanks